# How to get value of the button which is clicked on form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a small form with a reqired select and three submit buttons. The form should be send only if the select is selected. And now I need to get the data-value of the button which has send the form. 
How do I get this value? Important: The automated warning should appear if none select is selected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function() {
    var val = $("button[type=submit][clicked=true]").data['value'];
    console.log(val);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="post">

  <select required>
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="tt1">Test1</option>
    <option value="tt2">Test2</option>
  </select>

  <button type="submit" data-value=1>Go1</button>
  <button type="submit" data-value=2>Go2</button>
  <button type="submit" data-value=3>Go3</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This checks the button click instead of the form submission and returns the value of the event (click) target.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function(event) {
    if(document.querySelector('select').value) {
    var val = event.target.dataset.value
    console.log(val);
    }
    
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="post">

  <select required>
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="tt1">Test1</option>
    <option value="tt2">Test2</option>
  </select>

  <button type="submit" data-value=1>Go1</button>
  <button type="submit" data-value=2>Go2</button>
  <button type="submit" data-value=3>Go3</button>
</form>
```